# ¿Cómo guardar el contenido de un archivo txt en un vector de C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo x cantidad de números dentro de un archivo txt, necesito leer el contenido de ese archivo y guardar su contenido dentro de un vector.

```
vector<int> Numeros;
Par.open("par.txt");
while(Par, Numeros){
    // Guardar el contenido dentro de números
    // como si fuera una instrucción push_back()
}
```

Es un ejemplo del archivo par.txt

```
2
4
6
8
10
16
100
2222
```

Me gustaría hacerlo con un vector ya que tengo tengo que leer varios archivos de x cantidad de números para después utilizar un método de ordenamiento y el resultado guardarlo en un archivo nuevo. Mi plan es guardar todos los números de mis archivos txt en un solo vector para después ordenarlo.

Comment: prueba con mi solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi solución:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream infile("par.txt");
    string line;
    vector<int> Numeros;
    int numero;
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);

        if (iss >>numero)
            Numeros.push_back(numero);
    }

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = Numeros.begin(); it != Numeros.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
2 4 6 8 10 16 100 2222
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me funcionó muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la pregunta ya está respondida, te indico una forma un poco más simple de leer el fichero:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
  std::ifstream infile("data.txt");
  std::vector<int> Numeros;
  int numero;
  while( infile >> numero)
  {
    Numeros.push_back(numero);
  }

  std::copy(Numeros.begin(),Numeros.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
  std::cout << '\n';

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, con tu código me imprime 2 veces el último número del archivo, también lo intenté con un `for(int i = 0; i < Numeros.size(); i++)std::cout << Numeros[i] << " ";` y pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias por comentar. He editado la respuesta. ¿que tal así?